# Como abrir um teclado quando der "foco" em um EditText?

Tags: android

Tenho um EditText onde usei o `requestFocus()` para pegar o focus dele. Eu coloquei o `setFocus(true)` e o `setFocusableInTouchMode` também.

Quando abro a activity, o `requestFocus()` funciona, porém não abre o teclado e o TextWatcher que uso na mesma activity não recebe os dados que digito no TextView (Quando eu clico no EditText ele abre o teclado).

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer? E algum código também ajudava bastante.

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrar o teclado podes fazer assim:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.requestFocus();
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

ou em alternativa (eu costumo usar assim):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

se voce tem somente um EditText em sua activity basta voce usar os seguintes Attributes no seu manifest.xml

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

onde ? :

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" >

    ...................

  </activity>
```

com isso nao sera necessario o uso do `setFocus(true)` , `setFocusableInTouchMode()` ou o `requestFocus()`

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se no **Manifest** tem essa tag no activity:

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Se tiver, retire.

Answer (score 0):

Para você colocar o foco no *EditText*:

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

E para reverter (tirar):

```
editText.clearFocus();
```